# WebAPI: How basic authentication can work without the word basic

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

i was reading a write up with code example which was showing how to implement  basic authentication with api. the article link is https://www.infoworld.com/article/2990800/application-architecture/implement-http-authentication-in-web-api.html

see their client side code from where they are sending credentials to server.

```
public void BasicAuthenticationTest()
{
    string username = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("joydip"));
    string password = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("joydip123"));
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", username + ":" + password);
    var result = client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/IDG/api/default/")).Result;
    Assert.IsTrue(result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
}
```

specially see this line `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", username + ":" + password);`

there is no **basic word** exist **after Authorization word**....so how does it 
work?

rather signature should look like **Authorization: Basic anNtaXRoOlBvcGNvcm4=**

so please some one give me some knowledge about it.

last question can we return a token from server side in case of basic auth?
if possible share some knowledge how to return token in case of basic auth.

thanks

Comment: That code is also misleading on how to use the `AuthenticationHeaderValue` https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/AuthenticationHeaderValue.cs#L38

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An API is free to implement authorization in any way it wants. The *scheme* "Basic" is used by IIS on Windows to confirm a user account is correct but an API can use any scheme, or none.

There is nothing special about "Basic" other than it is a common convention. As long as the parameter value of the Authorization header is what is expected by the API it should work.

Comment: are you trying to say the code i posted here will work for basic auth. the word basic is just a convention not compulsory for basic auth.....am i right?

Comment: I can't know if it will work. It depends on how the service has implemented authentication/authorization.

Comment: here you said "There is nothing special about "Basic" other than it is a common convention" so from your statement i thought Basic the word is just a convention but not compulsory.

Comment: I don't think I'm being clear. Authentication is an implementation detail. You could make a header value of "MickeyMouse" and code your logic to validate the user. There are well known headers (like `Authorization`) and conventions often used (like "Basic Authentication") but when you write the authentication logic yourself it is completely up to you what to look for in headers or cookies or POST body or even (gasp) query string.